# regarding getting the good knowledge of android

Tags: android

I am new to android.I want to have good knowledge in android.Can anyone tell how should i proceed??

Comment: marking some of your questionsanswered , and doing a google search would be a good start

Comment: okkk,,,,Valentin.................Whats your email id.I want to chat you personally.....

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're talking about development for Android? The best place to start is the official Android dev-center.

[Android Developer center](http://developer.android.com/index.html)

There you will find everything needed for developing for Android. A good place to start is with the simple tutorials under the Resources tab.

If you haven't already set up the SDK check this out:

[Installing the SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html)

Comment: hey sondre how much time have u been working in android?Whats ur email id??

Comment: Haven't been working too much with android, but enough to know the android dev center is a very good place to start if you want to get into android development. Also http://mobile.tutsplus.com/ has alot of nice tutorials covering all parts of mobile development for all the most popular platforms